Python Image Error in different Directories
I have two .py files in different directories:
E:\Azy Projects\Python\PythonUsingVisualStudio\HellowPython\HellowPython\Operations\Apps\StyleReviews\ReviewSection_1_File.py

E:\Azy Projects\Python\PythonUsingVisualStudio\HellowPython\HellowPython\VisualExpertLogIn.py

in ReviewSection_1_File.py
    photo1 = None
def load_image():
    global photo1  # Reference the global variable
    #photo1 = None 

    try:
        # Load the image
        #script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        #root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(script_dir)))
        #image_path = os.path.join(root_dir, "Resources", "Images", "ApImage", "pyImage.png")
        image_path = "E:/Azy Projects/Python/PythonUsingVisualStudio/HellowPython/HellowPython/Resources/Images/ApImage/pyImage.png"

        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img = img.resize((100, 100))
        
        # Convert the image to a PhotoImage object
        photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        
        # Configure the label to display the image
        image_label1.configure(image=photo1)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error loading image:", e)







def ReviewSection_1 (GetMISUserID, Windos):
    # Create a new window for operations admin rights
    SizeSet_Top_window = tk.Tk()  # Use Tk() for new windows
    SizeSet_Top_window.title(" " + Windos)
    SizeSet_Top_window.geometry("1000x500")
    SizeSet_Top_window.configure(bg="white")
    # Add widgets and functionality to the new window
    # Example:
    label = tk.Label(SizeSet_Top_window, text="Operations Department")
    label.pack()


    frame = tk.Frame(SizeSet_Top_window ,   background="bisque",highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
    frame.pack(expand=False)
    #frame.pack()
    
    #frame.pack(fill=None, expand=False) 
    #frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
 



 
 
 

global image_label1

image_label1 = tk.Label(SizeSet_Top_window, text='images')
image_label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
 
load_image() 

if I am executing this ReviewSection_1 py file it work fine, but if I am loading this ReviewSection_1  from my another Login.py file, then image is not loading it shows error.
Error loading image: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Here my codes:
import tkinter as tk
import VisualExpertMainForm as DashBoard
from Connection import get_SecurityDBConnection

from OPerations.Apps.StyleReviews   import ReviewSection_1_File as ReviewSection_1 

    import pyodbc
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
     
    def login(username, password):
    
        ReviewSection_1.ReviewSection_1 (7,"Main")
        return
        except pyodbc.Error as e:
         
             # Display error message in the text widget
            error_text.config(state='normal')  # Enable editing
            error_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)  # Clear previous error messages
            error_text.insert(tk.END, str(e))  # Insert new error message
            error_text.config(state='disabled')  # Disable editing to make it read-only
            error_text.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2, padx=5, sticky='we'  )

Why does it work directly, and why not if I load the script from another script? Why does it add +1 at the pyimage?
